# iCloud Core Data Not Synching All Records On Second Device

Tags: core-data, synchronization, icloud

When I create a sqlite core data store in iCloud and seed on one device, it works fine and has around 6,000 records.  When I create the store on the second device, it syncs, but only ends up with around 4,000 records (presumably from the transaction logs).  My sync code in response to NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification reads...

```
    NSUndoManager * undoManager = [context undoManager];
    [undoManager disableUndoRegistration];
    [context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:info];
    [context processPendingChanges];
    [undoManager enableUndoRegistration];
```

However, when I insert a debug statement...

```
NSSet *updatedObjects = [[info userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
NSSet *deletedObjects = [[info userInfo] objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
NSSet *insertedObjects = [[info userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];

NSLog(@"found transaction log.  updated %d, deleted %d, inserted %d", updatedObjects.count, deletedObjects.count, insertedObjects.count);
```

I get an unexpected '0' for EVERYTHING, yet I know it's synching something because the database has around 4,000 records in it.

Does anyone have any advice on what might be going on here?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: Seems that when the second database is created it's using the transaction log to populate it, because if I delete the transaction logs the database is empty.  However, it doesn't seem to be populating all records.  How does it even know what the primary key is in order to resolve conflicts?  I don't remember declaring a primary key in the data model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look to the sqlite store itself, you will see that iOS is adding columns and tables to keep its reference. There's no way to add a primary key via code, unless you calculate it and store in a @property. But then again, core data doesn't care about it. Precalculated ID only serves you within your application logic.

For the iCloud part, you are right: iCloud transfer data by means of transaction log. The transaction log is copied to each device, and sqlite store get populated from there.

Documentation says that the transaction log is keep for a reasonable amount of time, then it is trashed. That could be the reason of only 4000 records instead of 6000.

Also, it is not your case, but beside that, in my experience, it is better to introduce iCloud since the beginning, when all devices are empty. If you introduce iCloud when device are partially filled with its own data, you could run into weird problems.

If you still haven't done that, I also suggest to turn on iCloud debugging in Xcode scheme.

My personal opinion, to synchronize more databases it is quite a difficult task, and I still wonder how it can be accomplished correctly by only dealing with transaction log sharing. Infact, at least with iOS 5 Core Data and iCloud was completely unreliable, and dangerous.